# Can't use Polish language diacritic characters in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, polish

I use Ubuntu 18.04

When I press <kbd>right Alt</kbd> + any diacritic letter, be it `a`, `c` or `s` I get nothing. Same goes for using <kbd>left Alt</kbd>+ any letter.

My input source is set to Polish.

Why can't I type in Polish?

Comment: This question from AskUbuntu may help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/127683/how-do-i-enter-polish-characters

Comment: Thank you, I read it before. I tried it all. It didn't help. Maybe because it was about Ubuntu 12.04 and I am on 18.04. I don't know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GNOME Tweaks I set `Keyboard & Mouse`-><kbd>Additional Layout Options</kbd> -> `Key to choose the 3rd level` -> `Right Alt`.

Now Polish diacritic characters work as expected.

Comment: It also can be reported as `3rd Level of <Less/Greater>`

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you have enviroment Virtualbox and Kali Linux, in my case the settings is as below

[Setting Keyboard PL in Kali Linux (Virtualbox)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpjfY.png)